# How to fill the missing gender data using the ratio in python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, missing-data

I want to fill the missing data of gender in proportion in a data set.

i use boolean index and head or tail function to select the top data i want, but when i use fillna function, it doesn't work.but after i try, it only run without boolean index, how can i get the top 3 empty values in example and fill it with 0.

```
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50).reshape((10,5)))
a[0][1,3,4,6,9] = np.nan
a[0][a[0].isnull()].head(3).fillna(value = '0', inplace = True)
```

the dataframe didn't fill the NaN

Comment: how about replace the number as 'F' and 'M'

Comment: you called fillna on the return value of head()... head does not return your original dataframe

Comment: a[0][a[0].isnull()].fillna(value = '0', inplace = True)

Comment: it also doesn't really fill the NaN

Comment: You're operating on a slice. I'll post an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with data:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50).reshape((10,5)))
a[0][1,3,4,6,9] = np.nan
```

gives

```
          0         1         2         3         4
0 -0.388759 -0.660923  0.385984  0.933920  0.164083
1       NaN -0.996237 -0.384492  0.191026 -1.168100
2 -0.773971  0.453441 -0.543590  0.768267 -1.127085
3       NaN -1.051186 -2.251681 -0.575438  1.642082
4       NaN  0.123432  1.063412 -1.556765  0.839855
5 -1.678960 -1.617817 -1.344757 -1.469698  0.276604
6       NaN -0.813213 -0.077575 -0.064179  1.960611
7  1.256771 -0.541197 -1.577126 -1.723853  0.028666
8  0.236197  0.868503 -1.304098 -1.578005 -0.632721
9       NaN -0.227659 -0.857427  0.010257 -1.884986
```

Now you want to work on column zero so we use fillna with a limit of 3 and replace that column inplace

```
a[0].fillna(0, inplace=True, limit=3)
```

gives

```
          0         1         2         3         4
0 -0.388759 -0.660923  0.385984  0.933920  0.164083
1  0.000000 -0.996237 -0.384492  0.191026 -1.168100
2 -0.773971  0.453441 -0.543590  0.768267 -1.127085
3  0.000000 -1.051186 -2.251681 -0.575438  1.642082
4  0.000000  0.123432  1.063412 -1.556765  0.839855
5 -1.678960 -1.617817 -1.344757 -1.469698  0.276604
6       NaN -0.813213 -0.077575 -0.064179  1.960611
7  1.256771 -0.541197 -1.577126 -1.723853  0.028666
8  0.236197  0.868503 -1.304098 -1.578005 -0.632721
9       NaN -0.227659 -0.857427  0.010257 -1.884986
```

Comment: @mujjiga not following? 4th NaN is row 6 which is still a NaN

Comment: @Will you are correct, I missed this part in the docs "If method is not specified, this is the maximum number of entries along the entire axis where NaNs will be filled. "

Comment: The answer got downgraded for some reason. Wish I knew why.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the loc function, otherwise you will never attribute a value. Here is what you could do :

```
a.loc[a[0].isnull().index[0:3], 0] = 0

In [1] : print(a)
Out[1] : 0  1   2   3   4
0   0.786182    -0.474953   -0.285881   -0.285502   -0.541957
1   0.000000    0.648042    1.104871    1.237512    -0.156453
2   -1.327987   1.851947    -0.522366   0.631213    -0.960167
3   0.000000    0.561111    -0.945439   -1.414678   0.433246
4   0.000000    -1.463828   0.141122    1.468288    0.649452
5   1.554890    -0.411142   -1.162577   -0.186640   0.774959
6   0.000000    -0.061410   -0.312673   -1.324719   1.763257
7   0.587035    0.265302    -0.793746   -0.148613   0.059330
8   0.909685    1.169786    -1.289559   -0.090185   -0.024272
9   0.000000    0.606329    -0.806034   1.102597    0.820976
```

Comment: Only first 3 nan's are supposed to be replaced